# Simplifying code, getting invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'

Tags: programming

I have a program that does 4 times the same thing with different parapmeters; and was trying to simplify my code to take one parameter as a variable.

Example (what was):

```
const char MQTT_PUB_IRRIGATION_TANK_VALVE[]      = "ArgyleCourt/Property/Hub/IrrigationTank/Valve";
const char MQTT_PUB_HOUSE_BOREWATER_TANK_VALVE[] = "ArgyleCourt/Property/Hub/HouseBoreWaterTank/Valve";

publishTankValveStatusIrrigation(false);

void publishTankValveStatusIrrigation(bool demandStatus) {
  if (demandStatus) {
    mqttClient.publish(MQTT_PUB_IRRIGATION_TANK_VALVE, "ON");
  } else {
    mqttClient.publish(MQTT_PUB_IRRIGATION_TANK_VALVE, "OFF");
  }
}

publishTankValveStatusHouse(false);

void publishTankValveStatusHouse(bool demandStatus) {
  if (demandStatus) {
    mqttClient.publish(MQTT_PUB_HOUSE_BOREWATER_TANK_VALVE, "ON");
  } else {
    mqttClient.publish(MQTT_PUB_HOUSE_BOREWATER_TANK_VALVE, "OFF");
  }
}
```

to one function now passing the topic also inot the function, thus needing only one function:

```
publishTankValveStatus(false, MQTT_PUB_IRRIGATION_TANK_VALVE);
publishTankValveStatus(false, MQTT_PUB_HOUSE_BOREWATER_TANK_VALVE);

void publishTankValveStatus(bool demandStatus, char topicToPublishTo) {
  if (demandStatus) {
    mqttClient.publish(topicToPublishTo, "ON");
  } else {
    mqttClient.publish(topicToPublishTo, "OFF");
  }
}
```

when I compile the simplified function, I get "warning: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]", but do neither understand why or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function declaration

```
void publishTankValveStatus(bool demandStatus, char topicToPublishTo)
```

declares `topicToPublishTo` as a `char`, that is, as a single character instead of as an array of characters that is constant.

Change `char` to `const char *` to say that  `topicToPublishTo` is an array of characters that is constant.

Comment: Thanks! Works :) You wrote `const char *`; is it permissible or good practice or even the same to write `const char*` ? This C business with single char, many char, and pointer really trips me all the time :(

Comment: @MaxG, both forms are ok; which to use is mostly personal preference. I think `const char*`, with the star close to char,  is used much more commonly than with a space between.  But if you are declaring several variables on one line (which some may frown on) it makes sense to associate the star with the variable name.  Eg, in `char *a, b, *c, d, e;`, only `a` and `c` are pointers vs. single characters.  Also, for the parameter declaration, some would say `const char topicToPublishTo[]` instead of `const char *topicToPublishTo`

Comment: Also see answers to  [const char * const versus const char *?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4949254), which cover examples like `char* astring`, `const char* astring`, `char* const astring`, and `const char* const astring`.  Note, answers to  [What is the difference between char * const and const char *?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/890535) might be more understandable.